# Doubt in Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory

I'm studying Information theory from the book `Information Theory, Coding and Cryptography-Rajan Bose`. I got confused at one pos where they have derived the equation (II)

> Consider a discrete random variable $X$ with the possible outcomes $x_i$, i = 1, 2, ..., n. The `self information` of the event $X = x_i$ is defined as $$I(x_i) = \log (\frac{1}{P(x_i)}) \tag{I}$$
>
> Now consider two discrete random variables X and Y with possible outcomes $x_i$, i = 1, 2, ..., n and $y_j$, j = 1, 2, ..., m. Suppose we observe some outcome $Y = y_j$ and we want to determine the amount of information this event provides about the event $X = x_i$, i = 1, 2, ..., n. i.e. we want to mathematically represent the mutual information.
>
> The `Mutual Information` $I(x_i;y_j)$ between $x_i$ and $y_j$ is defined as
>
> $$I(x_i; y_j) = \log(\frac{P(x_i|y_j)}{P(x_i)}) \tag{II}$$
>
> I'm not getting how they have come up with the above equation (II). I think It should be
>
> $$I(x_i; y_j) = \log(\frac{1}{P(y_j) \times P(x_i|y_j)})$$
>   $$= \log(\frac{1}{P(x_i) \times P(y_j|x_i)})$$

But either of the above two equations can not be able to equal to equation (II). Please tell me how they have come up with equation (II).

Reference : [Link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=AizEjrRIEHYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=true) (Page 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know information theory, but your source is *very clear*.
$$I(x_i;y_j) = \log\left[\frac{P(x_i|y_j)}{P(x_i)}\right]$$
is the **definition** of mutual information between $x_i$ and $y_j$.

Moreover, notice that
$$\frac{1}{P(y_j) P(x_i|y_j)} = \frac{1}{P(x_i,y_j)}=\frac{1}{P(x_i) P(y_j|x_i)}$$
and
$$\frac{P(x_i|y_j)}{P(x_i)} =\frac{P(x_i,y_j)}{P(x_i)P(y_j)}.$$
Thus
$$\frac{1}{P(y_j) P(x_i|y_j)}\neq\frac{P(x_i|y_j)}{P(x_i)}$$
and so I believe that
$$I(x_i;y_j)\neq  \log\left[\frac{1}{P(y_j) P(x_i|y_j)}\right]$$
and I do not believe that
$$I(x_i;y_j)\neq  \log\left[\frac{1}{P(x_i) P(y_j|x_i)}\right],$$
as you claim.

Answer (score 0):

Equation (II) is the *definition* of a different concept, (pointwise) mutual information. It's *not* the self-information (I) of a joint outcome.

The difference in the two notations is really subtle: the semicolon belongs to the notation in (II), and *you should have used a comma* to separate the outcomes of a joint variable when you wanted to use (I).

$$I(X=x;Y=y) = \log\frac{P(X=x\mid Y=y)}{P(X=x)}$$

$$I(X=x,Y=y) = \log\frac{1}{P(X=x, Y=y)}$$

They are different.